# How do I route traffic back over a VPN to other servers

Tags: iptables, routing, dnsmasq, ipsec, strongswan

I am currently setting up an environment in 2 sites. all servers are linux/ubuntu. First site is my office and second site is AWS.
I have 2 servers in AWS within a VPC with site to site VPN
Web01 - 172.31.24.106
Revproxy01 - 172.31.17.216

I have 1 server and 1 IP Camera in the office
Server1 - 192.168.102.1
Camera1 - 192.168.102.79

The VPN is on Server1 (IPSec Strongswan), and is configured to connect to a AWS site to site VPN at the AWS side.

With a lot of research and time Ive got everything up and running
Web01 & Revproxy01 can ping Server1
and Server1 can ping Web01 & Revproxy01.

My next step is to be able to ping Camera1 from Web01 & RevProxy01. I would eventually like to access the cameras http feed from web01 & Revproxy01

I think I need to setup the routing (on Server01) to pass the data from Web01 to Camera01 via Server1.

I would very much appreciate someones help and learn how to do this?

Comment: would you maybe mind to do a diagram of your setup for easier understanding of it, f.ex. with http://asciiflow.com/?

Comment: I will look at asciiflow.com now.

Comment: The formatting is off when I paste into here so please find the diagram at the below link

https://pastebin.com/raw/dSC0G7UL

Comment: The formatting is off when I paste into here so please find the diagram at the below link
https://pastebin.com/raw/f6N48KrQ

I should mention that on Server01 I have the hostapd service running, that enables my camera to connect to server01, as server01 acts as a wifi hostspot.
Server01 can access camera01

I suspect I need to configure some kind of rule to pass the traffic from my lan/VPN interface to my WLAN interface

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I do not know how much you understand how routing works, so I'll try to explain and we'll see how much sense you can make out of my explanation. The explanation is not exactly correct because in reality there are more wheels turning, but it should suffice.

At each hop in the network the IP stack looks at each incoming IP packet. It compares the **destination** IP address with its routing table. You can see that routing table with `ip route`.

First it checks whether the IP of the packet correspond to one of its own interfaces. If it does then the packet is destined for the hop itself and the hop "swallows" the packet (pushes it up the stack f.ex. towards the TCP stack).

If the packet wasn't destined for the hop itself, the hop checks and traverses its own routing table from most significant route to the least significant one. A `/24` tells you that 24 out of 32 bits are significant. A `/16` would be less significant then. In the case of `ip route` the IP stack would compare the IP address of the packet with the displayed routes from bottom to top. The first route that matches the packet's IP wins. So when traversing the routing table with a destination IP 192.168.102.10 the route 192.168.0.0/16 will match the packet. A route of 192.0.0.0/16 will not. You can use the `sipcalc` tool to show you network address informations.

The last matching route will be the default route that matches everything.

Each route contains the next hop, which is where the packet will be sent to. You can maybe see the next hop better in `/sbin/route -n`. It is the "router" column, or the "interface" column, depending on whether the network that the route represents is directly attached to a network interface that is present on the hop or not.

When a packet goes through a VPN tunnel, then the IP packet is wrapped in a different packet. So as far as you are concerned, only the internal IPs of the VPN entry and the exit point count. The packet plunks into to the entry point and plops out of the exit point "magically".

So now you should be able to determine at each hop which path the packet should take, including the source and the destination hops. If it doesn't take the path that you like then you have to add a corresponding route. That can be a single host route aka something like `192.168.102.79/32` (all bits significant! Matches only a single host!). Look up some examples for `ip route add`.

What you also want to do is to observe the packets traversing hops. You can use `tcpdump -n -i interface` for that (f.ex. `tcpdump -n -i eth0`). So if you see a packet traversing hop1 and you think it should be going to hop2, but you can't see it traversing hop2, then the routes on hop1 are probably wrong and are sending the packet to the wrong destination.

This way you should be able to analyse each routing table hop by hop, from your source to your destination, see which route the packet *should* take on each hop, possibly add routes so that the packet takes the correct path and verify that they indeed does with `tcpdump`.

Be aware that both the routes from source to destination **and** back need to be configured correctly.

Mind you that a wrong route can make the machine unreachable over the network. So you might want to have a way to reboot the machine with an independent mechanism than over the network.

Once your routing works make sure that it survives a reboot. F.ex. by writing the new route to `/etc/network/interfaces` (the place where you need to register this depends on how the network stack gets configured on that machine. This varies very much between different Unixes, Linux distributions etc.)

I hope this helps you further.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed info. I shall conduct some testing with the methods you have suggested....tcdump and familiarise myself with the interfaces file and the ip route add CMD.        I'll get back to you with the results...... Thanks again

Comment: I might want to add: running `tcpdump` will likely flood you with output. You can filter out what `tcpdump` is showing you f.ex. like this `tcpdump -n -i eth0 not port ssh and not host 192.168.102.1` will omit showing you ssh packets and packets destined for or originating from 192.168.102.1.